# Column space and Im(T) and the rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a connection between the Column space and Im(T) and the Rank?
Are there all equal (except the Rank which is the dimension)  ?

Comment: Indeed, yes they are!

Comment: The column space of $T$ and $\text{im}(T)$ are the same thing. The rank is the dimension of this subspace, sometimes it is so by definition, sometimes it is so because you can prove it.

Comment: @GitGud "sometimes it is so because you can prove it", ok.. and what is the definition of the rank in this case?

Comment: @Surb For instance the dimension of the row space.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. Let $T\colon V \to W$ and Let $T^t \colon W^* \to V^*$ be the transpose of $T$, $T^t(f) = f(T)$. If $B_V = \{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $B_W=\{d_1,\ldots,d_m\}$ a basis for $W$, let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ in the basis $B_V$ and $B_W$. Let $B^*_V=\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ and $B^*_W=\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$ be dual basis for $V^*$ and $W^*$. Now, the matrix of $T^t$ in the basis $B^*_V$ and $B^*_W$ is exactly $A^t$. Now $Im(T)^0 = Ker(T^t)$, but since $\dim(Im(T)) + \dim(Im(T)^0) = \dim(V)$ and then $\dim\ Ker(T) = \dim\ Ker(T^t)$. But since $\dim\ V^* = \dim\ V$ and $\dim\ W = \dim\ W^*$, we have $\dim\ Im(T) = \dim\ Im(T^t)$ and so the column space and row space are the same.